# How do I loop through all posts, in all custom post types

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have a site with loads of taxonomies, spread across 3 or 4 custom post types. What is the method to loop through those posts to get the last 5 or 10 posts, regardless of what post_type they're in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set post_type to any in WP_Query. More info [in documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters).

Comment: follow up to this... The solution mentioned above, `post_type=any`, returns posts & pages: not ideal.

The better solution is to find all registered & public post types and set that as your post_type array:

`$args=array('public' => true, '_builtin' => false); $post_types = get_post_types($args); query_posts(array('post_type' => $post_types));`